# Only replace pattern if the whole line matches regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am sure there is a trivial solution to this question but I can't seem to get it right:
**I want to replace a specific pattern in a line only if the whole line matches the regex.**

So in my case three pipes <kbd>|</kbd> should be replaced by underscores <kbd>_</kbd> only if the whole line is numbers and pipes:

```
|||10|||-80|||-120|||400           ---> replace
|||10|||asdf|||-120|||400          ---> don't replace
|||10|||-80|||400                  ---> replace
|||10|||-80|||-120|||400|||test    ---> don't replace
```

**Expected result:**

```
___10___-80___-120___400
|||10|||asdf|||-120|||400
___10___-80___400
|||10|||-80|||-120|||400|||test
```

**My attempts:**

```
\|\|\|(?=\-?\d+)
```

replaces the pipes if followed by numbers as expected but of course also in the "invalid" lines

```
^(\|\|\|\-?\d+){1,}$
```

matches the whole line and therefore I can't replace only the pipes

I understand why my patterns don't work and perhaps I have to simply do it with two passes but it feels like this should totally be possible.

Comment: The concept you're looking for is called "capture groups."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without more details, it seems you can use

```
(?<=^(?:\|{3}-?\d+)*)\|{3}(?=-?\d+(?:\|{3}-?\d+)*$)
```

Or, if you need to process *lines* in a larger string:

```
(?m)(?<=^(?:\|{3}-?\d+)*)\|{3}(?=-?\d+(?:\|{3}-?\d+)*\r?$)
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%5E%28%3F%3A%5C%7C%7B3%7D-%3F%5Cd%2B%29*%29%5C%7C%7B3%7D%28%3F%3D-%3F%5Cd%2B%28%3F%3A%5C%7C%7B3%7D-%3F%5Cd%2B%29*%5Cr%3F%24%29&i=%7C%7C%7C10%7C%7C%7C-80%7C%7C%7C-120%7C%7C%7C400%0D%0A%7C%7C%7C10%7C%7C%7C-80%7C%7C%7C400%0D%0A%0D%0A%7C%7C%7C10%7C%7C%7Casdf%7C%7C%7C-120%7C%7C%7C400%0D%0A%7C%7C%7C10%7C%7C%7C-80%7C%7C%7C-120%7C%7C%7C400%7C%7C%7Ctest&r=___&o=m).

[image]

**Details**:

- `(?<=^(?:\|{3}-?\d+)*)` - a positive lookbehind that requires that, immediately to the left of the current location, there is:

  - `^` - start of string anchor
  - `(?:\|{3}-?\d+)*` - zero or more sequences of 3 `|`s followed with an optional `-` (`-?`) and then 1 or more digits
- `\|{3}` - 3 pipes
- `(?=-?\d+(?:\|{3}-?\d+)*$)` - a positive lookahead that requires that, immediately to the right of the current location, there is

  - `-?\d+` - an optional `-` and then 1+ digits
  - `(?:\|{3}-?\d+)*` - 0 or more sequences of 3 `|`s + an optional `-` and then 1+ digits
  - `$` - end of string anchor.

C#:

```
var res = Regex.Replace(s, @"(?<=^(?:\|{3}-?\d+)*)\|{3}(?=-?\d+(?:\|{3}-?\d+)*$)", "___", RegexOptions.ECMAScript);
```

The `RegexOptions.ECMAScript` flag is used to make `\d` only match ASCII digits.

Comment: This really is a question in it self, but I hope you're OK with me directing it directly to you Wiktor - I was playing around with an answer to this and came up with this `(?<=^[\d|-]*)\|\|\|(?=[-\d|]*$)`. REGEX STORM however won't "accept" the `$` even though multi line is set. Can be solved by changing it to `(?:$|\r)`, but... Any idea why?

Comment: @ClasG: The line break style is `\r\n` there, but in .NET regex, `$` only matches before the `\n`, thus, `\r?` must be added before `$` when you test using a multiline string at RegexStorm. BTW, I would not use `(?<=^[\d|-]*)\|\|\|(?=[-\d|]*$)` if validation is key here (this will replace triple `|`s in a string like `||||||||||||||`).

Comment: Knew you'd have an explanation W. Thanks! Good to know.